# Get substring of unknowable innerHTML without creating orphaned tags?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm creating a show more/less feature for a biography and need to create a truncated preview version without breaking the HTML.

**Conditions:** The innerHTML of the biography element might contain divs, paragraphs, spans, or no HTML at all. Tags may also have inline styles. A traditional `str.substring(0, 400)` will break the page if it happens to split opening and closing tags of any kind.

What's the best approach to avoid orphaned tags?

```
const elm = document.getElementById("bio");
let fullHtml = elm.innerHTML;
let prevHtml;
prevHtml = fullHtml.substr(0, 450);
prevHtml = prevHtml.substr(0, Math.min(prevHtml.length, prevHtml.lastIndexOf(" "))); // truncates at last space to prevent mid-word truncation

// how do I make sure prevHtml doesn't have create orphaned tags?
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the HTML at all? Use CSS to set a max width and height when collapsed as well as truncating text via overflow on your container div

Comment: @RyanWilson because I have to append a toggle button, inline, at the end of the preview string. I suppose I can append it after the bio div which might not fly.

Comment: that seems like the way to go, you could always add a click event to the bio div to expand and collapse and skip the button altogether, else you could create two divs, one for truncated and other for full bio and toggle them

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing content and potentially breaking HTML you can show & hide content. Here is a layout with floating divs that have a fixed height of 50px and a button to toggle the full text on & off.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.bioWrapper button').click(function() {
    let isOpen = $(this).data('open');
    if(isOpen) {
      $('.bioWrapper').css({opacity: 1});
      $(this).text('⯆').closest('.bioWrapper').css({overflow: 'hidden'}).removeClass('clearFix');
    } else {
      $('.bioWrapper').css({opacity: 0.2});
      $(this).text('⯅').closest('.bioWrapper').css({overflow: 'visible', opacity: 1}).addClass('clearFix');
    }
    $(this).data('open', !isOpen);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 460px;
}
.bioWrapper {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px 3px;
}
.bioContent {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
.bioContent:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
.toggleButton {
  float: right;
}
.clearFix:before,
.clearFix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearFix:after { clear: both; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="bioWrapper">
    <div class="toggleButton"><button>⯆</button></div>
    <div class="bioContent">
      <b>Amber Arms</b>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bioWrapper">
    <div class="toggleButton"><button>⯆</button></div>
    <div class="bioContent">
      <b>Berta Bush</b>
      <div> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bioWrapper">
    <div class="toggleButton"><button>⯆</button></div>
    <div class="bioContent">
      <b>Charles Chaney</b>
      <div>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bioWrapper">
    <div class="toggleButton"><button>⯆</button></div>
    <div class="bioContent">
      <b>Dora Derham</b>
      <div>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```